# Проверка на вхождение элемента в массив с выводом наибольшего по совпадению из них. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Я масленок, в коде. К делу.

Вопрос: у меня есть слово и массив - как вывести предложение из массива которое содержит наибольшее кол-во совпадений данного слова из переменной? Т.е. как выдать второй элемент.

Я думал перевести в три массива потом посчитать, и вывести максимальное кол-во, но понял что это мне ничего не даст.) Да и это не работает, т.к. TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Но даже когда я перевожу в интеджер это не работает.)

```
testWord = "погода"
secondTestWord = ["интересная погода", "эта погода - лучшая погода", "хорошая погода"]

for someValue in secondTest:
   three = someValue.split()
   coinsidences = threeArrays.count(testWord)
   result = max(coinsidences)
   print(result)
```

И еще вопрос.
Что если например, переменная будет массивом и там будет два элемента, и смысл такой же, вывести из второго элемент где больше всего совпадений? Т.е.:

```
testWord = ["один", "два"]
secondTestWord = ["один два три", "один два два", "один"]
```

Прошу помощи, если можно пожалуйста с разъяснением, буду очень благодарен вам.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как вывести предложение из массива которое содержит наибольшее кол-во
>   совпадений данного слова из переменной? Т.е. как выдать второй
>   элемент.

Алгоритм:

- Подсчитываем длину первого текста и запоминаем длину и индекс
- Итерируем список начиная со второго элемента
- Сравниваем максимальную длину с текущей и обновляем их если нужно
- Выводим результат

Пример:

```
test_word = "погода"
words = ["интересная погода", "эта погода - лучшая погода", "хорошая погода"]

max_index = 0
max_number = words[0].count(test_word)

for i in range(1, len(words)):
    text = words[i]
    number = text.count(test_word)
    if number > max_number:
        max_number = number
        max_index = i

print(words[max_index])
# эта погода - лучшая погода
```

---

> И еще вопрос. Что если например, переменная будет массивом и там будет
>   два элемента, и смысл такой же, вывести из второго элемент где больше
>   всего совпадений?

Алгоритм тот же, просто адаптируйте проверку, подсчитывая сумму совпадений.

Пример:

```
test_word = ["один", "два"]
words = ["один два три", "один два два", "один"]

max_index = 0
max_number = sum(words[0].count(word) for word in test_word)

for i in range(1, len(words)):
    text = words[i]
    number = sum(text.count(word) for word in test_word)
    if number > max_number:
        max_number = number
        max_index = i

print(words[max_index])
# один два два
```

Answer (score 1):

В качестве альтернативы  предложенному в ответе **gil9red** варианту, можно использовать с  reduce:

```
from functools import reduce

testWord = "погода"
secondTestWord = ["интересная погода", "эта погода - лучшая погода", "хорошая погода"]

r =  ' '.join(reduce(
    lambda a,b: a if (a.count(testWord)> b.count(testWord)) else b, 
    [t.split(' ' ) for t in secondTestWord]
))
print(r)
```